# Validação com base em uma lista de palavras

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero validar um formulário com Jquery + JQuery Validation, utilizando uma lista de palavras autorizadas.

Ex: `var PalavrasAutorizadas = ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz' ];`

se ele digitar qualquer palavra que não esteja na lista ele invalide o formulário e não envie.

Consegui fazer justamente o contrário do que eu queria.
Só está autorizando se não está na lista, utilize essa resposta para montar esse script;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069086/validate-input-value-against-blacklist-array

**Exemplo no fiddler**
https://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/mfxn8mfj/2/

**Código javascript:**

```
var PalavrasAutorizadas = ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz' ];


jQuery.validator.addMethod("word", function(value) {
    return $.inArray(value, PalavrasAutorizadas) == -1;
}, 'a palavra não consta na lista');


$("#submit").validate({
    //errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},
    rules: {
        word: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert('Submitted');
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**:
Já tentei alterar pra 1 ou true o retorno do array, porém ao testar cada palavra não funciona para todas as palavras, creio que exista algum detalhe nessa função que não consigo perceber.

Comment: Não seria apenas mudar para return $.inArray(value, PalavrasAutorizadas) >= 0;

Comment: em teoria é, tentei tbm como true, mas mude lá e teste cada palavra, verá que algumas funcionam, outras não!

Comment: acho que tem mais algum detalhe faltando, mas não sei o que é.

Comment: Nesse fiddle inverti para 0, https://jsfiddle.net/mfxn8mfj/4/ consegue me  falar uma palavra que da erro para que eu possa procurar o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função inArray vai retornar a posição do array em que está o elemento procurado, quando não encontra, retorna -1. Mude a linha `return $.inArray(value, PalavrasAutorizadas) == -1;` por `return $.inArray(value, PalavrasAutorizadas) >= 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Cara, na doc do Jquery ele diz:

> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0 !== false), to check for the presence of value within array, you need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1.

Acredito que se você trocar a verificação pra

```
return !($.inArray(value, PalavrasAutorizadas) >= -1);
```

Não entendi muito bem a lógica do validator, mas pra fazer a verificação do array, acredito que seja desse jeito hehe